# Make viewport think max width is 1200px when window width is higher

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I make site which in test are full responsive. Almost all elements are scalable with vw units. It works great but on PC (window width > 1200px) site looks awful. I want to make site content on center with bars on sides. I tried setting body width or max-width to 1200px but vw units scales to window size. Is possible to set max-width for vw units? or I need to redesign page for PCs? I tried setting  but it does nothing in browser. [Screenshot how it looks like when set max-width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1b1e.jpg)

Comment: Depending on your website's content, perhaps you need to focus on Desktop-first ?  Mobile-first should _only_ be used for sites that make sense to use on a tiny screen with limited, inconvenient keyboards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you are willing to use a responsive framework like bootstrap, you have two options:

**Option 1: Media queries**

Use media queries to set different sets of styles for different ranges of resolutions. For example, anything contained in this query will only take effect if the viewport width is larger than 1200px:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    .container {
        width:5vw;
    }
}
```

**Option 2: Use vmin and vmax**

A nice trick I like to use is to use the `vmin` and `vmax` units for dimensions. This basically allows you to use the ratios of the screen to get your scaling right. For example:

```
.container {
    height:100vmin;
}
```

This element's height will be equal to whichever one (width or height of the viewport) is smallest. Therefore its height will always fit in the viewport.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can't give you  +1 cuz of reputation :( After asking this question I invented that I can load other .css when resolution >1200px and in that .css change all vw port units to percent of 1200px. E.g. if element has width: 15vw I will  set 15%*1200 px.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it with (`VW, VH`) formatting should work.

Here is an example of a `<div>` that is fully responsive with `VW, VH`

```
.div_scroll
    {overflow-y: scroll;
        display: block;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        position: absolute; 
        border: 3px solid #dddddd; 
        height: 75vh;
        width: 79vw;
        margin: 0px;
        background-color: white;
        transform: translate(0vw, 14vh);}
```

You can specify minimum and maximum as

`min-width: 10vw; 
 min-height: 10vh; 
 max-width: 10vw; 
 max-height: 10vh;`

The number is the % of the viewport. So let's say you would have a `<div>` and you want it to fill out a maximum of 80% of the viewport (The viewport is not the monitor but the window) You would do it like:

```
max-width: 80vw;
max-height: 80vh;
```